# Using constants in abstract Objective-C classes?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, oop, inheritance

First of all, let me clarify that I know you cannot have actual abstract classes in Objective-C. When I say abstract I mean I am not creating any instances of the class, but am simply using it as a base class for inheritance.

My abstract class contains a NSInteger. All the classes inherited from this abstract class will need to use this integer. Once set, the NSInteger will be never be changed. The value of the NSInteger though will vary depend on the derived class. Since it will never be changed, I want to make the variable const. The thing is though, if I make it const, I would have to set the value upon instantiation. Therefore I would have to set the value in the base abstract class- however then I can't adjust the value based on the derived class it exists it.

I realize this is hard to understand so I created some basic pseudocode. I used an NSString as an example, but in my program it is an NSInteger:

```
Class animal: const NSString soundItMakes = "Sound" //the constant integer
//since soundItMakes is const I have to set it upon instantiation even though it doesn't make sense in the base class

Class dog: animal //derives from animal. Needs to change the const soundItMakes to fit a dog however since it was already set in animal, the base class, I can't really change it

Class cat: animal //derives from animal. Needs to change the const soundItMakes to fit cat however since it was already set in animal, the base class, I can't really change it.
```

I do not want to remove the variable from the base class and instead put it in each derived class nor do I want to make it non-constant. Does anyone see a solution to this? I realise this is confusing so if any more information is required feel free to ask.

I am using Cocoa in Xcode 3.2.6 in Mac OS X Snowleopard.

Comment: Why not just define a readonly property on your superclass, then each subclass can implement the getter method to return what they need. That would be the canonical OO way to do it I think, unless I totally missed your point.

Comment: Why should it remain a variable? What keeps you from making a method that returns it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically I would address this with a method rather than an ivar.

```
@interface Animal : NSObject
+ (NSString *)soundItMakes;
@end

@implementation Animal
+ (NSString *)soundItMakes {
  NSAssert(NO, @"Abstract");
}
@end

@implementation Dog
+ (NSString *)soundItMakes {
  return @"bark";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First: I may just use a `Animal` protocol in this case.

Second: If you really want a variable for the class, here's one approach (which you can adapt for the compiler version you are using):

```
@interface MONAnimal : NSObject
{
@private
  int animalCode;
  NSString * soundItMakes;
}

// designated initializer -- treat as protected
- (id)initWithAnimalCode:(int)inAnimalCode soundItMakes:(NSString *)soundItMakes;

... just don't declare setters for animalCode or soundItMakes!

@end
```

Then you'd say:

```
@interface MONMoonBear : MONAnimal
@end

@implementation MONMoonBear

- (id)init
{
  return [super initWithAnimalCode:MONAnimalCode_MoonBear soundItMakes:@"Eating Garlic and Berries"];
}

@end
```

There are a few blanks to fill in yet - but that is a push in the direction of one approach.

Comment: +1 This is a good approach in some cases (I typically use a class method instead, but this approach has its uses). The more important take-away from this answer is the suggestion of making `Animal` a `@protocol`. That is an oft-overlooked solution.

Comment: +1 to yours too - I'd have added that if you had not beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Make `soundItMakes` a method or `@property(readonly)` that is overridden in the child classes.  You have no choice but to redefine in each class if the value is different for each class anyway.

```
// Animal.h
@interface Animal : NSObject
- (NSString *)soundItMakes;
@end

// Animal.m 
@implementation Animal
- (NSString *)soundItMakes
{
    // Throw exception, assert, etc.
    // This will force you to implement the subclass
    return (nil);
}

// Cat.h
@interface Cat : Animal
@property(readonly) NSString *soundItMakes;
@end

// Cat.m
@implementation Cat
@synthesize soundItMakes = _soundItMakes;

- (Cat *)init {
   NSString * const soundMade = @"Meow";

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
        _soundItMakes = soundMade;
    return (self);
}
@end
```

Comment: Note that `const NSString *` is meaningless. You mean `NSString * const`. `NSString` is immutable by its nature, so the former doesn't do anything. The latter prevents `soundMade` from being reassigned to another object, which is what you actually mean.